# Mutating a mutable Struct within a Swift Task

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, actor

We are experiencing a few crashes on a diffable data source.

The view model that holds the business logic has few structs marked as `var`, hence they are mutable.

Those structs can be changed on the main thread or in an event handler that wraps a Swift `Task`.

I'm wondering if within the `Task` is safe to mutating structs (adding or removing elements) even if the structs are sendable by default. On the contrary, I'm asking if they should be accessed by means of an `Actor`.

```
final class MyModelRepository {
    private var items: [MyModel] = []
    private(set) var uniqueKeys = Set<String>()

    // run on the main thread
    func removeAll() {
        items.removeAll()
        uniqueKeys.removeAll()
    }

    ...

    // scheduled through a scheduledTimer    
    func eventHandler() {
        Task {
            do {
                let updates = try await retrieveUpdates() // call an API service to retrieve the updated updates
                updateItemsPublisher.send(updates.updatedValues) // sinked on main thread
                for item in updates.removed {
                    items.removeAll { $0 == item }
                    uniqueKeys.remove(item.key.orEmpty)
                    guard let deletedModel = // find the deleted model locally to the app
                    deleteItemPusblisher.send(deletedModel) // sinked on main thread
                }
            } catch {
                // log the error here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Rob. Thanks. Yes it was typo. The struct is mutable since there is a `var`. I will provide an example asap. Thanks, Lorenzo

Comment: @Rob I've updated with a MRE. Thanks a lot, Lorenzo

Comment: @Rob please feel free to answer the question (since reopened). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> I'm wondering if within the Task is safe to [mutate] structs.

As a general question, it is safe to do so if and only if:

- the property is actor-isolated, and
- you are invoking `Task {…}` from a method that is isolated to the same actor.

`Task {…}` creates a new top-level task on behalf of the current actor (if any). So, no, you don’t have to introduce a new actor if it is already actor-isolated.

Now, in your example, there are two problems.

1. We are not in an actor-isolated context. We would generally make the type an `actor` rather than a `class`, or we would isolate this class to some global actor (such as `@MainActor`). See
2. Even if we were, you suggest that `eventHandler` is being called by a `Timer`, i.e., not from a Swift concurrency context. In Swift concurrency, rather than a `Timer` we might have a task with a `try await Task.sleep` call, which would preserve whatever actor-isolated context from which you invoked it.

I might suggest you see WWDC 2021’s [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/) or 2022’s [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351)

---

Here are some safe and unsafe examples:

```swift
// struct
struct Foo {
    var bar: String
}

// unsafe because neither property nor method are actor-isolated; `Task {…}` is not actor isolated, either
class UnsafeClassExample {
    var foo = Foo(bar: "baz")
    
    func thisIsUnsafe() {
        Task {
            foo.bar = "qux"
        }
    }
}

// safe because actor (thus property and method are actor-isolated); `Task {…}` will be actor isolated, too
actor SafeActorExample {
    var foo = Foo(bar: "baz")
    
    func thisIsSafe() {
        Task {
            foo.bar = "qux"
        }
    }
}

// safe because whole class (including both property and method) is actor-isolated; `Task {…}` will be actor isolated, too
@MainActor
class SafeActorIsolatedClassExample {
    var foo = Foo(bar: "baz")
    
    func thisIsSafe() {
        Task {
            foo.bar = "qux"
        }
    }
}

// safe because both property and method are actor-isolated to same global actor; `Task {…}` will be actor isolated, too
class SafeActorIsolatedPropertyAndMethodExample {
    @MainActor var foo = Foo(bar: "baz")
    
    @MainActor func thisIsSafe() {
        Task {
            foo.bar = "qux"
        }
    }
}

// safe because `UIViewController` is actor-isolated to `@MainActor`, and therefore behaves like `SafeActorIsolatedClassExample`
class SafeViewController: UIViewController {
    var foo = Foo(bar: "baz")
    
    func thisIsSafe() {
        Task {
            foo.bar = "qux"
        }
    }
}
```

Your example, even before we get to the problem that `Timer` introduces, is not safe, akin to the `UnsafeClassExample`, above.

---

As an aside, I would avoid introducing [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency) with `Task {…}`, but the original question was re `Task {…}`, hence my usage above.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Really appreciated. Just a clarification. When you write the following **you are invoking Task {…} from a method that is isolated to the same actor**, you are referring, for example, to a `Task` within a `UIViewController`. Since the latter belongs to the main actor, then the task will inherited the context and hence it will be run on the main thread as well. Correct?

Comment: Correct. A type method is actor-isolated if either (a) the type is an `actor`; (b) the type is explictly isolated to a global actor (such as `@MainActor`); (c) the type inherits global actor isolation from its superclass (e.g., `UIViewController`); (d) the type adopts a protocol that is isolated to a global actor; or (e) that individual method is explicitly isolated to a global actor. So, yes, a `UIViewController` subclass method is isolated to the main actor.

Comment: But, again, the aforementioned `Timer` caveat still applies. Use `Task.sleep` (which, unlike traditional `sleep` functions, is non-blocking) in lieu of `Timer`.