Swift Concurrency - Why my Task didn't inherit the parent Task's executor and priority
When creating Task A from Task B, I thought Task A will inherit from Task B. But when running the following code I created, why did line 14 printed debug 4: <NSThread: 0x30361a300>{number = 6, name = (null)}. Why it isn't main thread, just like the other prints?

Here's the code for anyone who wants to run locally:
struct Test {
    func test() {
        print("debug 3:", Thread.current)
        Task {
            print("debug 4:", Thread.current)
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        Task { @MainActor in
            print("debug 1:", Thread.current)
            Task {
                print("debug 2:", Thread.current)
                Test().test()
            }
        }
    }
}


The function test is not actor-isolated. Thus, its Task {…} is not actor-isolated either. (If test was actor-isolated, then its Task {…} would be a top level task on the same actor. But test not actor-isolated, so that is moot.)
In Swift concurrency, a function’s isolation is either explicitly defined or inherited from the type in which it is defined, if any, but it does not “inherit” it from the caller.

Thanks @Rob! How would I mark this function as actor isolated?

You theoretically could just add a global actor qualifier to the function definition, e.g., @MainActor func test() {…}. But it’s a little strange to have an isolated function on a struct because it’s a value type (with which we generally achieve thread-safety by just giving each thread its own copy). We probably need to see a practical example of where you are trying to do in test to advise you further. I might also refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76868102/1271826, which, while walking through a different question, illustrates both safe and unsafe interaction with a struct.

Thanks @Rob, yes this makes sense. I also posted an answer that builds on top of yours. Let me know if it looks wrong, thanks!

I made some additional examples to explain on top of @Rob's answer.

Example 1:


Because test() is nonisolated, it will use a background thread, so debug 3 prints a bg thread. The Task created on line 13 is a top level Task and is not bound to any actor, so it used a random bg thread in this case.


Example 2:


UIViewController is using MainActor, so both debug 3 and debug 4 run on the main thread, as test() is a function on a MainActor class.


Example 3:


Similar to example 1, debug 3 and debug 4 will use bg thread, because test() is nonisolated function, even if it is in a MainActor class




Rather than “random background thread”, one might note that it is a thread from the “cooperative thread pool” (which, by the way, we should avoid blocking since this pool is limited to the number of cores on your device).

And note that in Task {…} in viewDidLoad, the @MainActor in is redundant. The UViewController is isolated to the main actor, as are its methods in your subclass, so the Task is already isolated to the main actor.

Thanks for the notes! Yes the @MainActor is redundant, I added it only to make it explicit this is on MainActor
